# Inner bbox offset

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

I need some kind of bbox(or draw a line with inner offset of 50 px) with inner offset, but offset should be in pixels. Is there any way to do it? 
is the only way is with map.unproject?
thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be part of the map, or could you simply do it in HTML on top of the map?

Comment: it shoul be a part of the map, geojson line

Comment: Then yes, you'll probably need to listen for map update events and use map.unproject to update the geographic coordinates.